# How to recognize spoofed email programmatically?

Tags: node.js, email, imap, spoofing

I am using nodejs library (`inbox` library from npm) to check my IMAP account every minute. If I find email I will process it and do many things with it on my database. The problem I am currently facing is how to recognize is the email I got to my IMAP server was really from email owner and was not spoofed? How can I check it programmatically in nodejs? Using any algorithm or library, or just checking the headers of email?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mailbox provider should do the [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) check and include the result somewhere in the headers. There you could retrieve the information "spoofed, not spoofed, undetermined". How this header is called could vary between different server softwares. In my header (done by exchange online) it contains `Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)`

Btw. SPF only works if the "other side" implements it. So it's not a 100% thing.